# Автозаполнение web-формы

Tags: post, javascript, get

Есть сайт https://www.dropbox.com/login

Как сделать ярлык для автоматического входа с подстановкой логина и пароля?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на ваш вопрос - userscript'ы.

http://vizr.ru/page/tri-greasemonkey-scriptish-jquery-userscript-dlja-oblegchenija-web-serfinga

http://habrahabr.ru/post/129343/

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы вся реализация работала в адресной строке, а не в виде отдельного файла.
И нужна подсказка именно по этому конкретному сайту, потому как то что я подставлял не работает...